# Deploying SharePoint layout ASP .NET assembly into GAC

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, deployment, gac, sharepoint-feature

I'm currently rewriting a legacy SharePoint application and I need to figure out how to deploy it.
The application itself is SharePoint solution with several features, including webparts and simple web pages with some code.

There is a webpage that is designed to be deployed in `layouts` subfolder.
In production environment, there is no codebehind in `layouts` subdirectory, just the `.aspx` file.

I understand that corresponding codebehind assembly is loaded from GAC. Indeed, it is there.
However the page code doesn't contain `<%@ Assembly %>` directive that would ask it look in GAC, nor does it specify fully-qualified name:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BadWolf._Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <!-- -->
</html>
```

**So how does this page locate its code assembly in the production environment?** I need to deploy the same code to a different server but  if I don't specify `<%@ Assembly %>` SharePoint gives me Unknown Error, which is represented in logs as follows:

```
Exception Type: System.Web.HttpException
Exception Message: Could not load type 'BadWolf._Default'.
```

What did I miss? Is there any special config, any special setting, whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the assembly was in SharePoint `bin` folder, that's why it was loaded without specifying the fully qualified name. **However removing it from GAC yielded another issue:**

> Request for the permission of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission, Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' failed

This is funny because removing the assembly from either GAC or `bin` folder makes it unusable (or else requiring additional configuration which I seek not), **and I'm not sure which one is actually being loaded.**

I think I'll stick with keeping assembly in GAC (to have full trust) and specifying fully qualified name.

Comment: If it's in the bin, you probably need a CodeAccessSecurity policy for the assembly in place in your web.config for that web application (a right PITA, tbh).

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what drives my decision to put it into GAC. It's legacy code and I don't want to spend time evaluating what it may or may not do.

Comment: Actually, I have the same issue (MOSS 2007, custom ASP.NET application under SP LAYOUTS): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421286/asp-net-dll-required-in-both-gac-and-inetpub-wwwroot-bin I have no problem installing the assembly in the GAC but it is very disconcerting to have to leave it in the BIN folder as well. So, should I add the `Inherits=` or @Assembly directive? I really wish to take it out of the BIN folder.  Please advice. Thanks!

Comment: In my case, it was missing the <% Assembly %> directive in the ASPX page as well as in a ASCX page control. Adding those resolved the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Inherits= with the fully qualified assembly name...

```
Inherits="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MyClass, MyAssembly, version=1.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=123456789"
```

Comment: It works this way. But what I can't figure out is **how does this work in production without assembly directive or attribute?**

Comment: The Assembly attribute is only used in TagPrefix directives (I thought)

Comment: Which pages are you seeing this in? Application Pages or Layout Pages?

Comment: Just found an answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032724/deploying-sharepoint-layout-asp-net-assembly-into-gac/5033042#5033042 . Thanks for helping.

Comment: Oh, there's another interesting detail there, you might want to take a look (see my answer).